# What is the shape of the loops of an ideal solenoid?

Tags: magnetic-fields

With a real solenoid made up of circular loops, it can be seen that the magnetic field lines curve around the ends. The curving effect would be less for a rectangular geometry. But an ideal solenoid would be of infinite length, in that case, would it matter if the loops were circular or rectangular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the magnetic field inside an infinite solenoid, invariant under translation in the infinite direction, is
$$B=\mu_0nI$$
where $n$ is the number of loops per unit of length for **any** geometry of the loops (circular, square, …)